# Hiding left / rightBarButtonItem based on how view controller is presented

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am trying to reuse view controller (let's call it aVC) in an app flow. I can show aVC by either modal presentation or pushing view controller on navigationController.

I have rightBarButtonItem code in view did load that setup right bar button item which I am only using when aVC is presented modally. I was wondering if there is any way to hide that button when I use pushViewController for aVC instead of modal presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect if view is pushed or presented by many ways:

1) detect existance of navigation controller (Pushed)

```
if self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count > 0
{
    if self.NavigationItem != nil
    {
        self.NavigationItem!.setLeftBarButtonItem(nil, animated: false)
        self.NavigationItem!.setRightBarButtonItem(nil, animated: false)
    }
}
```

2) detect if view is (Presented Modally)

```
if self.presentingViewController != nil
{
    //View is presented
}
```

Then to show/hide buttons you can use

```
  for item in self!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems! // may be rightBarButtonItems!
    {
        item.enabled = true
        item.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()  You can change color
    }

// To hide items 
        if self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems != nil
        {
            for item in self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems!
            {
                item.enabled = false
                item.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            }
        }
```

or you can set buttons as nil

```
if self.NavigationItem != nil
{
    self.NavigationItem!.setLeftBarButtonItem(nil, animated: false)
    self.NavigationItem!.setRightBarButtonItem(nil, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, This is exactly what I was looking for.